# call a controller in other module

Tags: controllers, magento-2.1.7

I've installed a module and I need to get some value from frontend and pass it to a controller in my module.

is it a good practice to update in other module `js` files that are not created by me? and is it ok to call a controller in other module

Comment: Best practice is to override the controller by your custom module and define the sequence in module.xml, since because 3rd party extension has to be upgraded once in a while @YomnaMansour

Answer (score 0):

1. You can override that .js file in your theme and do customisations (either you can override complete file or may also create [mixins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html))
2. Yes you can use controller of other module but do not forget to add that module as a sequence in your custom module's module.xml
   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Comment: does mixin let me override the whole js file or only the functionlity I need to override.
in other words. should I write the all file or only function I need to modify

Comment: You can override the file if you have much more customisations, I have attached the link having details about mixins. You should prefer using mixins but if it doesnt work you can override the js.

Comment: You wont be able to override the whole js file using mixins. In order to override place same file with same name in your theme folder. As if their is a file related to checkout, you need to place same js file in your theme at app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/....